# How stored procedure output instead of rows count?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

My stored procedure always returns 0. I tried unique data and duplicated but the insert is done with success but the return value is always the same `@new_identity = 0`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAddAuthor]
    @Author tyAuthor READONLY,
    @new_identity INT = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- check if the author exists 
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Id_Author FROM dbo.Authors 
                   WHERE (dbo.Authors.Username = (SELECT Username FROM @Author) 
                          OR dbo.Authors.phone = (SELECT phone FROM @Author) 
                          OR dbo.Authors.email = (SELECT email FROM @Author)))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.Authors (Username, sexe, email, phone, address) 
            SELECT [Username], [sexe], [email], [phone], [address] 
            FROM @Author 

        -- output the new row 
        SELECT @new_identity = @@IDENTITY;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- get the author Id if already exists
        SELECT @new_identity = (SELECT TOP 1 Id_Author 
                                FROM dbo.Authors 
                                WHERE (dbo.Authors.Username = (SELECT Username FROM @Author) 
                                       OR dbo.Authors.phone = (SELECT phone FROM @Author) 
                                       OR dbo.Authors.email = (SELECT email FROM @Author)))
     END
 END
```

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `@@IDENTITY` to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/). Also - are you sure that your table `Authors` does in fact have an `INT IDENTITY` column at all?

Comment: `Username = (SELECT Username FROM @Author)` is going to fail if there is more than one row in the TVP, you should change `=` to `IN`. Or better, do it as a proper join `JOIN @Author tvp ON tvp.Username = a.Username OR tvp.phone = a.phone OR tvp.email = a.email)` and use table aliases to make your code more readable.

Comment: Username is unique in the table @charlieface. And thanks for the advice

Comment: I tried scope_identety and   the result are the same. But  my gole is to insert  new row if not  exists and  return the id if the new row or return the id.  If the row alredy exists can scope_identety get the id of the existing row ?. Sorry for my english

Comment: Any case you need to return **multiple** IDs because your TVP may have multiple rows. So instead of returning a single value in a parameter, change your `INSERT` and `UPDATE` to [include `OUTPUT inserted.AuthorID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

I found that in the declaration of the parameters I put null beside the output and that what caused the problem.

```
@new_identity INT = NULL OUTPUT
```

but I don't understand why, I thought the 'null' was like the default value, or when  you try to make the parameter optional you add null as default value.
can someone explain, please?